How to use validate schema in mapping data flow whose source is paramaterized SAP CDC dataset
I have a requirement that we don't want to change the schema of the dataset in our destination (which is ADLS) when there is a change in source (SAP BW).
I have created a mapping data flow with a source having the SAP CDC dataset which has ODPNAME, ODPContext, loadType, and runMode parameterized.
I disabled the "Allow schema drift" option and tried two things first enable "Validate schema" and 2nd disable all options.
But when I went to validate or publish the change it started throwing this error:

Schema should be defined in the dataset or enable allow schema drift

So, I went to define a schema in the dataset but there is no option for the schema in the SAP CDC dataset.
Could anyone please help me here I am stuck with this issue?
Also, the projection option is not helping as the pipeline is parameterized the ODPName and ODPContext are taken at runtime. Or if I am missing something then please do let me know.

Do you want to fail the dataflow or not ingest any data when the schema is not same? and based on your explanation, the sink dataset is a fixed one right when you know the schema prior to the execution?

I want to fail the data flow. Sink ADLS Storage account is fixed but based on source object name I am creating different files to keep data of different object.

The validate schema option will not work in case of parameterized and dynamically changing schema. It can be used when you imported the projection, and the data changed later during the dataflow run.
In this case, you can use assert transformation to fail the dataflow. Follow the below dataflow design.
After all of your transformations on your source, take a derived column and create a new column source_col_names and give the expression ColumnNames() like below.

Now, take another source and give your target ADLS dataset for this. Similarly, take another derived Column transformation and create a new column target_col_names with same expression ColumnNames().

Now, compare both of these array columns using assert transformation condition like below.
Upon derivedColumn2 take assert transformation and add derivedColumn1 transformation in the Additional streams. Check on Fail data flow and select Expect exists. Give any description and in the expression select the source_col_names and target_col_names from both transformations.

If first row of source_col_names from derivedColumn2 i.e., the column names array of the source does not exist in the target column names array, the dataflow will fail. Otherwise, this will go to the next transformation.
Next, use a select transformation Rule-based mapping, to remove the extra created columns like below.
(name!='target_col_names')&&(name!='source_col_names')


Add your target dataset again in the sink. If the schema is same, it will copy the source data to the target file. Otherwise, the dataflow will fail like below.


Sorry for replying late. But, I just want to add something more, in adls we have partition based on load time which like - bronze/table_name/load_year=2024/load_month=08/load_day=17/load_hour=0016. So, when I give path till table_name and preview the data from source2 I am unable to see load_year and load_month columns. Maybe it is because of load_year and load_month has single value, I am not sure. And columns from load_year to load_hour are created using derivedColumns after source1. So, when I put your derivedColumns and assert it fails as in source2 it could not find year and month.

In that case, you need to add the step of getting column names after your derived columns. Whatever operations that you want to do on the source, do it before the step of getting column names so that all the column names from your source will be extracted before the assert.

Do you have idea why I am not getting load_year and load_month from source2 even though I have folder of those both have only one value i.e. load_year=2024 and load_month=10. Could it be that due to only one value I am not seeing this columns.

AFAIK, when the data is partitioned through folders, the columns which are used for partitioning won't be there in the files. If you want the columns to be there, you need to create those using derived column and pass your values to those to the dataflow from pipeline using dataflow parameters. After creating required columns, then get the list of column names and go ahead with assert transformation.
